# pandas: when data is NaN logic operations cannot be done

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame in Pandas and 2 columns can have values or be NaN (Null) when not assigned to any value.

I want to populate a 3rd column based on these 2. When not NaN it takes some value. This works as follows:

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: import numpy as np

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, np.NaN],['John', 'Malone'],[np.NaN, np.NaN]], columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   col1    col2
0   NaN     NaN
1  John  Malone
2   NaN     NaN

In [20]: df['col3'] = np.NaN

In [21]: df.loc[df['col1'].notnull(),'col3'] = 'I am ' + df['col1']

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   col1    col2       col3
0   NaN     NaN        NaN
1  John  Malone  I am John
2   NaN     NaN        NaN
```

This also works:

```
In [29]: df.loc[df['col1']== 'John','col3'] = 'I am ' + df['col2']

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   col1    col2         col3
0   NaN     NaN          NaN
1  John  Malone  I am Malone
2   NaN     NaN          NaN
```

But if I not make all values NaN and then try this last loc, it gives me an error!

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, np.NaN],[np.NaN, np.NaN],[np.NaN, np.NaN]], columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN

In [33]: df['col3'] = np.NaN

In [34]: df.loc[df['col1']== 'John','col3'] = 'I am ' + df['col2']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    552             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y,
--> 553                                           raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)
    554         except TypeError:

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    217         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 218                          **eval_kwargs)
    219     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, **eval_kwargs)
     70         _store_test_result(False)
---> 71     return op(a, b)
     72

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in _radd_compat(left, right)
    805     try:
--> 806         output = radd(left, right)
    807     except TypeError:

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in <lambda>(x, y)
    802 def _radd_compat(left, right):
--> 803     radd = lambda x, y: y + x
    804     # GH #353, NumPy 1.5.1 workaround

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3b2873f8749b> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[df['col1']== 'John','col3'] = 'I am ' + df['col2']

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    616                 lvalues = lvalues.values
    617
--> 618             return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
    619                                      index=left.index, name=left.name,
    620                                      dtype=dtype)

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    561                 result = np.empty(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)
    562                 mask = notnull(x)
--> 563                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)
    564             else:
    565                 raise TypeError("{typ} cannot perform the operation {op}".format(typ=type(x).__name__,op=str_rep))

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in _radd_compat(left, right)
    804     # GH #353, NumPy 1.5.1 workaround
    805     try:
--> 806         output = radd(left, right)
    807     except TypeError:
    808         raise

c:\python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in <lambda>(x, y)
    801
    802 def _radd_compat(left, right):
--> 803     radd = lambda x, y: y + x
    804     # GH #353, NumPy 1.5.1 workaround
    805     try:

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

It is like if Pandas didn't like the Column value == some text if all values are NaN????

Help!

Comment: "Help!" -- what does help look like in this case? You can use a `try` block to catch the error. You could first check if all of the the values of a column are `NaN` before doing an operation. You haven't really asked a question, so it'll be tough to give a concrete answer.

Comment: On SQL I would be able to do this very easily as Nulls would not make the logic fail. In this case having NaNs (on all values) causes the previously working line to work. So hopefully somebody can point at a proper way of doing the operation I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that really all this line is doing is doing is adding a string to column 1 values if there are any values that are not null.

```
df.loc[df['col1'].notnull(),'col3'] = 'I am ' + df['col1']
```

So you can just check if there are any values that are not null and then only perform the operation if there are:

```
if df['col1'].notnull().any():
    df['col3'] = 'I am ' + df['col1']
```

You also don't need to create the col3 column prior to running it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if an entire column is `np.nan`, it's probably stored as floats, not object (text).

So you can do:

```
if not np.all(pandas.isnull(df['mycol'])):
    df = my_string_operation(df)
```

You could also coerce the column in question to an `object` type.

```
df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].astype(object)
df = my_string_operation(df)
```