# DataFrame logic operations with NaN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to do some comparisons in a pandas DataFrame.

```
# create simple DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(['one', 'two', 'three'], range(1,4), columns=['col1'])
#df:
#    col1
#1    one
#2    two
#3  three

# assign one col1 value to be NAN
df.loc[1, 'col1'] = np.nan 
# this comparison works
print(df['col1'] == 'three')

# assign all col1 values to NAN
df.loc[:, 'col1'] = np.nan
# this comparison fails
print(df['col1'] == 'three')
```

The first comparison (with only one NAN value in the column) works as expected, but the second (with all NAN values in the column) produces this error: `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

What's going on here?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278265/pandas-when-data-is-nan-logic-operations-cannot-be-done), which suggests some possible but kind of hack-y solutions to this problem.

But why is this the behavior happening in the first place?  Is this restriction useful, somehow?  I can fix it by using `df.fillna('')` before my comparisons, but this seems clunky and irritating.

So my questions are:
1.  What is the cleanest way around this issue?
2.  Why is this the default behavior, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `col1` is of type `float` after assigning all `np.nan` so trying to compare to a `string` throws a `TypeError`. :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['one', 'two', 'three'], range(1, 4), columns=['col1'])
df.loc[1, 'col1'] = np.nan

    col1
1    NaN
2    two
3  three
```

Assigning a single `np.nan` to a column that contains `string` values leaves `dtype` object:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 1 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
col1    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

But all `np.nan` values converts to `float`:

```
df.loc[:, 'col1'] = np.nan
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 1 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
col1    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: Thanks -- this is really helpful.  I was sticking to what I thought was the standard for pandas, but this has helped me understand the type issue a little better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by using the `ix` indexer rather than `iloc`, in which case the datatype of the series isn't changed (not sure why this is, presumably both types of indexers should have consistent behaviour, my preference would be to change `iloc` to match `ix`):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['one', 'two', 'three'], range(1,4), columns=['col1'])
>>> df['col1'].ix[:] = np.nan
>>> df.dtypes

col1    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had done:

```
# assign all col1 values to None
df.loc[:, 'col1'] = None
```

Then

```
# this comparison does not fail
print df['col1'] == 'three'

1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```